# React Native: Unable to resolve module fs

Tags: npm, react-native

```
Unable to resolve module fs from /...mypath
```

I got this error when trying to import a node module into my react-native app.

The module used 'fs' in this way:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var list = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/list.json', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: did you do `npm install fs --save` ?

Comment: fs is one of the node core modules. I don't think I need to install it. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

React Native applications do not run in the Node.js environment (it is only used by the packager to actually serve and compile your application bundle).

Since your app is running inside JS VM on either iPhone or Android, the only way to access filesystem is to use [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) or any other 3rd party module that utilises bridge connection to talk to the platform specific native APIs.

Comment: Thanks, how about the tls module? I can't seem to find an alternative for it. Do you happen to know any?

Comment: As in every case, think of iOS/Android instead of Node.js. You'll need a module that wraps native APIs, try looking for one - if there's none, you'll need some native knowledge to wrap it yourself.

Answer (score 21):

I ended up using '**rn-nodeify**' to include fs into React Native. You can use most of the node core modules this method. Install it with npm:

```
npm install rn-nodeify
```

Then in **package.json** file, add the following line in "scripts" to specify which modules you want to include in your RN project. For example, I used **fs**, **crypto** and **https**, and the line goes

```
"postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto,fs,https --hack"
```

Comment: For me the error appeared when I installed and tried to use `"@google-cloud/vision": "0.11.0"`. Unfortunately, this hack has not helped.

Comment: @gumkins, did you find a solution or alert google-cloud team of the issue? I'm also having the same problem with the vision api on a react-native client.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hack is not working for me as well, I am trying to use "mssql-ssrs": "^1.3.12" in react-native expo project, "expo": "^35.0.0"

Answer (score 4):

it took me a while to find the issue, I'm sharing it as it might be useful for future reference (using react native with Expo):

One of my coworkers accidentally imported in one of our react components  `app.config.js` in the project root to read some configuration rather than using `expo-constants`.

it was causing it to read the .env file from the react native wrapper that obviously doesn't have the `fs` lib.. this is the first line of our `app.config.js`:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
```

the correct way for reading settings inside `app.config` is:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const appConfig = Constants.manifest;
```

Answer (score 2):

Install  [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) (follow the instructions at de link), so weather the error persist, enter at the directory ('./node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/build/commonjs/env/) search by the file: (creatFileSystem.js) and edit:

```
fs = require('fs')
```

to:

```
fs = require('react-native-fs')
```

I don't know if this is recommended way, but was the only that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a json list just call it direct.

Example:

1. import subscriptionData from './assets/dataSource/subscriptionData.json';
   or
2. var subscriptionData = require('./assets/dataSource/subscriptionData.json');

You don't need to convert it, and you can use to import your data or the way you want.

```
    function installJson() {
      console.log("Iniciando Importação");
      subscriptionData.forEach(item => {
        firestore().collection('subscription').add(item);
      });
    }


    subscriptionData.json
    [{
    "code": 325,
    "name": "bla bla bla"
    },
    {
    "code": 356,
    "name": "ble ble ble"
    }]
```