# How do I make fs work, I've tried so many options but I can not make it work

Tags: android, ios, react-native

For react native, I am trying to use fs. It says

```
While trying to resolve module `fs` from file `/Users/bbq/project/app/screens/folder.js`, the package `/Users/bbq/project/node_modules/fs/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/bbq/project/node_modules/fs/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function readFile(filePath) {
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile(filePath);
    console.log(data.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Got an error trying to read the file: ${error.message}`);
  }
}
```

What to do?

Comment: It looks like [you can't use `fs` in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046429/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-fs), as that's a Node-specific module. But there are third-party modules like [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) that can help.

Comment: I downloaded it, but when I try to link it it says that react-native command not found. Is linking it necessary? And if it is, what can I do about the react-native command not found(can npm replace it?).